# Perl: Merging columns with the same names and keeping row names

Tags: perl, rows, multiple-columns, names

What I essentially want to do is take a table like this one, where the top row contains columns names:

```
A    B    B    B
a    9    8    9
a    6    5    3
b    4    4    5
b    8    3    4
```

and merge the columns with the same names while keeping the corresponding row names (contained in the first column) like so:

```
A    B
a    9
a    8
a    9
a    6
a    5
a    3
b    4
b    4
b    5
b    8
b    3
b    4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you have "A B B C C\n1 2 3 4 5\n", what output do you want?  "A B C\n1 2 4\n1 3 5\n" or "A B C\n1 2 4\n1 2 5\n1 3 4\n1 3 5\n"?  And if the former, what about "A B B C C C\n"?

Comment: "A B C\n1 2 4\n1 3 5"

Comment: so what should "A B B C C C\n1 2 3 4 5 6\n" produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is 'melt' a table. I've used a library for this in R but not in Perl. There is a Perl module called `Data::Table` which does have a melt function for multidimensional lists.

Comment: I'm actually doing this in R! I'll look up the documentation on melt. Thank you.

Comment: Its been a while so I'm assuming you already found the right library. If not take a look at the Reshape2 package. :)

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/reshape2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize your initial table (T1) as:

```
0    1    2    3
A    B    B    B
a    9    8    9
...
```

where you have columns 0 .. 3.  Each time you print the lines of your transformed table (T2), you'll be printing column 0.  So T1's line 1 ("top row") would be the following line 1 of T2:

```
0    1
```

T1's line 2 would be the following three lines of T2:

```
0    1
0    2
0    3
```

Each of T1's lines, from line 2 to its last line, will transform into three lines of T2--in the pattern shown above.

Psudocode:

1. Get a line of T1
2. split the line into its elements
3. Is it line 1 ("top row") of T1?  If so, print elements `0` and `1` with a newline. Go to step 1.
4. It's not line 1 of T1. Print the following, each on its own line: elements `0` and `1`, elements `0` and `2`, elements `0` and `3`.
5. Go to step 1.

When a file or `DATA` is being read using `while`, how can you get the current line number?  Perl uses `$.` to store that information.  So if `$. == 1`, it's line 1.

Hope this helps!